# checkSelfPermission nullpointer 6.0

Tags: android

I have a problem with a check permisions always says nullpointer my debug in 6.0:

what am I doing wrong

```
public String getGeolocation(Context context){

    try{        
        int MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION = 1000;         

        if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION);
        }
        if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //return 0 ;
        }
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); // Here is nullpointer
        //Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if(location != null && location.getTime() > Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - 2 * 60 * 1000) {
            // Do something with the recent location fix
            //  otherwise wait for the update below
        }
        else {
            //mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,  0, 0, this);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){}
return geo;

}
```

// I use this method to get data :

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        Log.v("Location Changed", location.getLatitude() + " and " + location.getLongitude());
        geo = ""+location.getLatitude() + " , " + location.getLongitude();
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }
}
```

Error exception from Android studio :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
```

Where I call getGeolocation() ?

```
public class AlarmReceiverCustom extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
getGeolocation(context)
```

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: I edited and pass context correct, and wrong line correct sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Where do you call `getGeolocation()`?

Comment: in a function that call when pass 24h (alarm service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're giving a context to `getGeolocation()`, still you're calling `getSystemService()` on the object itself.

You might want to use the context you passed:

```
mLocationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

But you have to consider the [Receiver and Process Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle) too:

> A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to `onReceive(Context, Intent)`. Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active. [...]
>
> This means that for longer-running operations you will often use a Service in conjunction with a BroadcastReceiver to keep the containing process active for the entire time of your operation.

So you better reimplement this part of your application and use a Service to update the location.

Comment: Yes now the object not is null, but never called my function "onLocationChanged()"

Comment: @WarpCalimCpl it's the `BroadcastReceiver` you're using. You should read a little about it.

Comment: Hi @tynn I read about the class BroadcastReceiver , my class extends from service but I need call a BroadcastReceiver, rarely call "onLocationChanged", I don't know how to send geolocation in background :(

Comment: I only need get once time location (without overrides because I send data instant)

Comment: @WarpCalimCpl create an Intent for doing so and call `context.startService(intent)`. From the service then call `getGeolocation()`. But this task is too broad for a comment.

Comment: Okey I post another post

Answer (score 1):

From the error, you are trying to use `getGeolocation()` before `onCreate()` is even called. If you are doing something like this:

`private String LOCATION = getGeoLocation(this);`

than that would be the source of your error. You would need to move the initialization of the variable to inside `onCreate()`.

Comment: In particular, it needs to be after the `super.onCreate()` call.

Comment: I updated, I call from BroadcastReceiver with your context

Comment: @CommonsWare it doesn't complain when being called before `super.onCreate()`.